Running C++ Geant4 Program on mutliple CPU cores
I was running a simple program on Geant4, compiled from C++. When I ran it, it froze, presumably because my computing power is limited. But I noticed something very interesting, in my system monitor, the CPU usage was fluctuating between two of the CPU cores. Why is this and is it possible to utilize more cores at the same time?
Picture of the screen

Yes, you can run Geant4 in multi-threading mode, but it requires some preparations. You can learn about the built-in multi-threading support in Geant4 here for example CERN, Parallelism in GEANT4.
I have also encountered such CPU usage fluctuations, and not only with Geant4 programs. I'm not sure about reasons for this behaviour.
